# sed delete the line start with # but not with #! (shell scripts)

Tags: sed

To delete the line with `#` , the following line can work:

```
sed -i "/^\(\\s\)*\\#/d"
```

but what I want is to delete lines that start with `#` and not with `#!`.

Answer (score 13):

`sed -i -e '/^\s*#\([^!]\|$\)/d'`

Where:

- `^` start of line
- `\s*` zero or more whitespace characters
- `#` one hash mark
- `\([^!]\|$\)` followed by a character which is not `!`
  or end of line.

Answer (score 9):

```
sed -i -e '/^#!/p' -e '/^#/d' file
```

This will go through the file line by line and when it finds a line starting with `#!` it will be printed by the first expression. Then it will be deleted from the pattern space by the second expression (i.e. it will not be printed a *second* time by the default `p` command which is in effect when not using `sed -n`).

A line starting with just `#` will be ignored by the first expression, but deleted by the second expression.

Any other line will be printed by the default `p` command.

To allow for blanks in front of the `#` (and delete those lines too):

```
sed -i -e '/^[[:blank:]]*#!/p' -e '/^[[:blank:]]*#/d' file
```

The `[[:blank:]]` expression will match a space or tab character.

---

As Stéphane mentioned is comments, changing `p` to `b` in the first expression would allow the `sed` script to continue with the next line of input without considering the second expression, if the first expression matches. The `b` command branches to a pre-defined label, or to the end of the `sed` script if no label is given. This would be an optimization.

Comment: See `b` instead of `p` to _branch off_.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Yes, that would be a small possible optimization.

Comment: Maybe comment that only the first line could be a shebang and that this modification of your code does work on that case: `sed -e '1{/^#!/p}' -e '/^\s*#/d' file`

Comment: Possibly, but there may be text files that are scripts that contain here-documents that are also scripts...

Answer (score 6):

To *"and"* two addresses, you need a command group (`{...;}`):

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*#/{/^#!/!d;}' < file
```

With GNU `sed`, you can use `-i` for inplace, replace `[[:space:]]` with `\s` (assuming a recent version) and omit the `;`:

```
sed -i '/^\s*#/{/^#!/!d}' file
```

You can nest several, but beware that portably, you can't have anything after the `}`. So for *A and B and not C and not D*, that would be:

```
sed '/A/{/B/{/C/!{/D/!d;}' -e '}' -e '}' < file
```

Or:

```
sed '
  /A/{
    /B/{
      /C/!{
        /D/!d
      }
    }
  }' < file
```

Comment: Up-voted for educational value. Teach a man how to fish and all that…

Comment: Why the redirection `< file` if sed could read the file?

Answer (score 4):

Use the [negative look-ahead](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Lookaround-Assertions) in Perl:

```
perl -ne 'print unless /#(?!!)/'
```

This removes lines containing `#` not followed by `!`. If you want to match the # only at the beginning of a line, probably preceded by whitespace, use

```
perl -ne 'print unless /^\s*#(?!!)/'
```

Answer (score 2):

Abstract: remove all non-shebang comments.

```
sed -e '1{/^\s*\#/{/^\#!/!d}}' -e '1!{/^\s*\#/d}' file
```

---

Your command modified to use single quotes (no double `\\`):

```
sed '/^\(\s\)*\#/d'
```

will almost work correctly by just adding the detail that (after the #) there must be anything that is not an asterisk `[^!]` `sed '/^\(\s\)*\#[^!]/d'. But that will fail with a line that is empty after the comment (`#`) character.

For that we need to assert that the line has ended (`$`).

For that we will need the use of extended syntax `([^!]|$)`:

```
sed -E '/^\s*\#([^!]|$)/d'
```

Or, more portable:

```
sed -E '/^[ \t]*\#([^!]|$)/d'
```

However, for an script, only the first line that start as `#!` matters.
All other lines that start with optional space and a # are comments:

```
sed -e '1{/^#!/!d}' -e '1!{/^[ \t]*#/d}' file
```

Which means:

First `-e`

> if the first line start with a comment (space and #) but does not start exactly with #! it is erased.

Second `-e`

> other lines (`1!`) that start with an optional space and # are removed.

Comment: For completeness, -r is supported by GNU sed since 3.01 (1998) (initially --rxtest, not documented, changed to --regexp-extended and documented in 3.95 in 2002) -E added for compatibility with BSDs in 2009 (4.2), documented in 4.3. -E in FreeBSD since 2000 (-r for GNU compatibility in 2010), NetBSD since 2002 (-r in 2008), OpenBSD both -r and -E in 2009. busybox -r in 2004, -E in 2014. -E is the one that will be added to POSIX (and why -E was added to busybox and documented in GNU).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$ cat test.sed 
  # delete this one

  #! don't delete this one

        # delete this too
```

Command:

```
$ sed -i -e '/^[[:space:]]*#[^!].*/d' test.sed
```

Result:

```
$ cat test.sed 

  #! don't delete this one
```

---

Well, this command **won't delete** lines with just a lonely `#`. So, I keep this answer to show why you need to refer to other solutions.

Comment: Try it with a lone `#`. It will not be deleted, whereas it should be per OP.  Reason? The [^!] consumes one character. There is no concept to look arounds in sed.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you want to delete all comment lines (starting with any amount of white space followed by `#`) except the she-bang which *needs* to be in the first line to be detected.

You can use the very same substitution command if you restrict it to only regard everything beginning from line 2; in `sed` notation that is the range `2,$`. You restrict `sed` commands to a range by prefixing them with that range:

```
sed "2,${/^\(\\s\)*\\#/d}"
```

or with shell quotation that allows for more readable back spaces and without unnecessary regular expression grouping:

```
sed -e '2,${/^\s*#/d}'
```

### Example

Input:

```
#!/path/to/a/shebang-command
# This is the first comment

command 1
  # another comment
  command 2
# Final comment
```

Output:

```
#!/path/to/a/shebang-command

command 1
  command 2
```